# Strategy in StringConcatFactory

Tags: java, string-concatenation, java-9

I have know the invokedynamic instruction.

Also I have known the basic process how it implements. But when I arrive the code. I can't understand the code in `StringConcatFactory`.

Can you tell me how the six strategies implements by the source code. Only the default strategy is also done. As a university student, I can't under the source code.

```
private enum Strategy {
    /**
     * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
     */
    BC_SB,

    /**
     * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
     * but trying to estimate the required storage.
     */
    BC_SB_SIZED,

    /**
     * Bytecode generator, calling into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder};
     * but computing the required storage exactly.
     */
    BC_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

    /**
     * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
     * This strategy also tries to estimate the required storage.
     */
    MH_SB_SIZED,

    /**
     * MethodHandle-based generator, that in the end calls into {@link java.lang.StringBuilder}.
     * This strategy also estimate the required storage exactly.
     */
    MH_SB_SIZED_EXACT,

    /**
     * MethodHandle-based generator, that constructs its own byte[] array from
     * the arguments. It computes the required storage exactly.
     */
    MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`makeConcat()` and `makeConcatWithConstants()`, which are `StringConcatFactory` API entry points, both use `doStringConcat()`, which produces a `CallSite` used by the `invokedynamic`.

`doStringConcat()` calls `generate(Lookup, String, MethodType, Recipe)` which contains the following switch on the enum you are asking about:

```
switch (STRATEGY) {
    case BC_SB:
        return StringConcatFactory.BytecodeStringBuilderStrategy.generate(lookup, className, mt, recipe, StringConcatFactory.Mode.DEFAULT);
    case BC_SB_SIZED:
        return StringConcatFactory.BytecodeStringBuilderStrategy.generate(lookup, className, mt, recipe, StringConcatFactory.Mode.SIZED);
    case BC_SB_SIZED_EXACT:
        return StringConcatFactory.BytecodeStringBuilderStrategy.generate(lookup, className, mt, recipe, StringConcatFactory.Mode.SIZED_EXACT);
    case MH_SB_SIZED:
        return StringConcatFactory.MethodHandleStringBuilderStrategy.generate(mt, recipe, StringConcatFactory.Mode.SIZED);
    case MH_SB_SIZED_EXACT:
        return StringConcatFactory.MethodHandleStringBuilderStrategy.generate(mt, recipe, StringConcatFactory.Mode.SIZED_EXACT);
    case MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT:
        return StringConcatFactory.MethodHandleInlineCopyStrategy.generate(mt, recipe);
    default:
        throw new StringConcatException("Concatenation strategy " + STRATEGY + " is not implemented");
}
```

1. `BytecodeStringBuilderStrategy` handles `BC_SB`, `BC_SB_SIZED` and `BC_SB_SIZED_EXACT`. It generates the same `StringBuilder`-using byte-code that `javac` would generate if you just wrote the concatenation in your Java code. The major difference is that this byte-code is generated at runtime (and not compile time) and loaded using `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass()`.
2. `MethodHandleStringBuilderStrategy` handles `MH_SB_SIZED` and `MH_SB_SIZED_EXACT`. It uses `MethodHandle` machinery (including `MethodHandle` composition) to build the same concatenation chain on top of `StringBuilder` calls. It does not use any private APIs (like `Unsafe`), so it is probably the least non-portable strategy.
3. `MethodHandleInlineCopyStrategy` handles `MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT`. It also uses `MethodHandle` machinery to build concatenation chain with `MethodHandle` composition, but instead of `StringBuffer` it works with a byte array directly, avoiding copying where possible. To do it, it uses some internal APIs and some knowledge about JDK implementation details (like `String` constructor that avoids copying string bytes). So this implementation is more fragile (to JDK changes), but also it allows more speed.

### A little summary

We can see that the three differ in two aspects: **a)** what is used as a buffer to build up the string and **b)** how the concatenation chain is created.

1. `BytecodeStringBuilderStrategy` (`BC_SB_xxx`) uses `StringBuilder` and runtime code generation.
2. `MethodHandleStringBuilderStrategy` (`MH_SB_xxx`) uses `StringBuilder` and `MethodHandle`s
3. `MethodHandleInlineCopyStrategy` (`MH_INLINE_SIZED_EXACT`) uses byte array and `MethodHandle`s.